# how to reset values to null for second user if two different users applying for same order

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Sorry in advance if you find my English/question hard to understand.

I am making an order apply function where users with different email addresses apply for orders. For first user who apply, everything is right but when different user applies for the same order, it shows order is already applied from its account too. How can i reset the field to NULL for new user.

Also, adding 'OR $oa_rows['user_email'] != $_SESSION['user']' is giving me int 1 and no button to click.

```
<?php
    $oa_sql = "SELECT * FROM order_applied RIGHT JOIN users ON 1=1 WHERE user_email = '$_SESSION[user]' ";
    $oa_run = mysqli_query($conn, $oa_sql);
    while($oa_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($oa_run)){
        echo '<div>';
        if($oa_rows['oa_status'] == NULL || $oa_rows['oa_user_email'] != $_SESSION['user']){ 
            if($oa_rows['oa_status'] == 'cancel' || $oa_rows['oa_status'] == 'applied' && $oa_rows['oa_user_email'] == $_SESSION['user']){
              echo '<div style="display:none">
               <form method="post">
                  <input type="hidden" name="oa_status" value="applied">
                  <input class="btn btn-sm btn-info" type="submit" name="oa_status_submit" value="Apply For Order">
               </form>
              </div>'
          } else {
             echo '<div>
            <form method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="oa_status" value="applied">
                <input class="btn btn-sm btn-info" type="submit" name="oa_status_submit" value="Apply For Order">
            </form>
              </div>';
            }
        } else {
            if($oa_rows['oa_status'] == 'applied'){ 
                echo '<a href = "order_details.php?o_id='.$rows['_id'].'&new_status=cancel" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" >Cancel Request</a>';
            } else {
                echo '<a href="order_details.php?o_id='.$rows['_id'].'&new_status=applied" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" >Apply For Order</a>';
            }
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

Comment: Maybe some if else over ternary operator... that is hard to read

Comment: Thanks nerdlyist for your comments and very sorry you suggest an edit and I mistakenly rejected it... Yes, I used ternary operator In fact twice... You can see this "$oa_rows['oa_status'] == 'applied'" condition has different ternary operator...

Comment: the first ternary operator checks if there is field available in database. If no, then it inserts a field. if we have field inserted already then second ternary operator just update the request to cancel or reapply. I hope now you have got what I am currently doing

Comment: I made an edit with if else statements. What you have is not very readable and in my opinion not really the point of ternary operators. Also changed OR to ||.

Comment: Based on these updates are you still getting the unexpected behavior?

Comment: Thanks a lot... The || solves it... I will replace my code with yours. Can you tell me how to hide the button once clicked. unfortunately, its showing both buttons... and making a button list when multiple users apply for single order... For instance, [cancel request] is a button and below list shows number of rows submitted in database from different users... 
Its like 
[apply for order]
[cancel request]
[cancel request]
[cancel request]
[cancel request]
[cancel request]

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I follow the issue now. Are you getting more then one user returned from your SQL?

Comment: I am giving you link to an image which can make you understand what is the problem dropbox.com/s/js35palw5npujb2/apply%20order%20error.JPG?dl=0 after applying first time, apply for order button disapper...but when different users make request it starts to appear again and showing to every user who apply on order... so that user can make multiple request which shouldn't happen ... i have updated the code too with div style="display:none" to let you know what I have done. I believe there is something I am overlooking

Comment: What does the database order_applied look like?

Comment: Hello Nerdlyist.. Sorry for late response. .. following is the image of table
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nw0kkgg7krflsae/order_applied.JPG?dl=0
Whenever a user applies for order, it creates a row with unique id that has all his details...and these rows are listing as I have shown in previous image..

Comment: Thanks nerdlyist for all your help... I have been able to find out the root cause.. That while loop was creating that problem. I am all good now... Thank you very much for all your help... but that doesn't mean you are free :D I mean I may look for your help again, if you are available

Comment: Glad I could help but as for your issue with the button I would highly recommend looking at your query over the code. Joining users on 1 = 1 seems very odd.

Comment: Yeah, actually, it was done for null only... I had in mind if a user hasn't applied for order before, the table will give null values if I filter it with its email address... Also, I wasn't able to retrieve an empty table  with the table that contain values... so on this forum, somebody recommends that and I tried and it worked...

Comment: Hello Sir... Just looking for your help. I recently posted a question and seeking your help if possible.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37922584/send-email-in-wordpress-with-phpmailer-code-on-click