# Send Email In WordPress With PHPMailer Code on Click

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to send an email in wordpress. This code works fine If I send email with simple php file but when I am pasting that file in wordpress along with this code, nothing happened. I am sure there is something I am not aware of.

```
if(isset($_POST['details_submit'])){    

        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->isSMTP();                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                     // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Host = $smtp_server;                 // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->Username = $username;                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = $password;                // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587;                          // TCP port to connect to

        $mail->setFrom("orders@test.com", "Orders Test");

        $mail->addAddress('mark@aol.com', 'Mark');   // Add a recipient

        $mail->isHTML(true);  // Set email format to HTML

        $bodyContent = 'testing message';
        $mail->Subject = 'Hello Checking' ;
        $mail->Body    = $bodyContent;
        $mail->AltBody = $bodyContent;

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo "Message could not be sent.";
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Mailer Error: '. $mail->ErrorInfo.'</strong></div>';
        } else {
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Message has been sent</strong></div>';
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: where are you "pasting" this?

Comment: Thanks Gerald for quick answer. just above the form code in php tags... I am not sure if there is something I have to add in functions.php...

Comment: This code works fine If I send email with php file without wordpress... but when I am pasting this file in wordpress along with this code, nothing happened.

Comment: Are are including the file for the PHPMailer class?  Any errors?  Method is POST on form?  `details_submit` name given to button?

Comment: Yes Progrock, using phpMailer. If there would be an issue in locating the phpmailer.class file. it will give an error. No errors, everything else is fine. Like I said,  I did use that file alone and checked it. Then I add it in wordpress theme...Now it should send a simple email on  click but it doesn't.
<form method="Post">
                              <input type="submit"  name="details_submit" value="send" id="form_submit" onClick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Order Form', eventAction: 'Calculate Price'});"></form>

Comment: is there anything I have to add in functions.php or it works fine?

Comment: Please edit additional information into your question instead of posting them as a comment. They are much better readable there. Apart from that: WordPress by default disables error reporting, so you most probably have to enable it again to see error messages.

Comment: Note: you should NOT edit files of a theme or plugin you didn't write yourself. On the next update of the theme or plugin all your modifications will be gone. If you want to edit a theme, create a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and do your modifications there.

Comment: Thanks Gerald. I look into it... Thanks for your help.